# Pattern for recognizing data with different categories

Tags: machine-learning

I have many records, but they are described by different types of values. Is there a way to recognize patterns about machine learning for example and predict what they are.

Training data:
`Apple: Color = Red, Color = Yellow, Category = Fruit 
Pear: Color = Green, Weight = 230, Category = Fruit
Potato: shape = round, category = vegetable`

Test data:
`color = green, weight = 230, category = fruit 
-> pear`

It's hard to explain but I hope the example explains the problem a bit.

Comment: I think SVM can be useful when you have lots of features, small number of samples, and lots of missing features on samples. This is base on 'hands on machine learning with sklearn and tensorflow'

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `design-patterns` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever in your data you already have instances of the target, you can apply supervised learning methods, for instance KNN, ANN, regression etc.
if you have many records you can surely feed data into an ANN. by setting the fruits as Y vector and the features as X features.

Comment: Because of the different categories I don't know how to enter it. Normally it has such a form? 
`x = [[red,round],[green,round],[yellow,round]]

y = [apple, apple, pear]`
But what would it look like if you had different categories?

Comment: One possible way to solve the problem is to fill the missing data, there are many different possibilities to solve this problem, you could try for instance Amelia (link: https://gking.harvard.edu/amelia) or fill with average values

Comment: Sorry I haven't answered yet. The problem is that there are thousands of combinations of the single categories and always new ones are added. That's why I don't think it makes sense to fill it up with dummy values. is there no way to recognize it by patterns, it doesn't have to be about machine learning either.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're asking. Not all the data samples have the same feature categories. There is not correct answer here. Basically, there are few standard options here:

The first one is to get a set of attributes that all data samples have in common. This is the fastest solution. But problem here is that you may end up in the situation where you can be left with one attributes that all of the samples have in common.

Second approach would be to fill the data with missing attributes. This process could be long if you have a lot of data, but this model will definitely give you the best results.

The third solution here would be to create and train the model that can take the image and describe it with attributes. For example, if you give it an image of a tomato, it could output:

```
shape = round
color = red
category = fruit
```

This model should be pretty easy to train and be very accurate. With it, you can fill in the gaps in your dataset and train the inital model.

I hope this helps :)